# Multi Label classification with Binary Relevance with factor variables

Tags: classification, factors, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use multi label classification(Binary relevance). Many predictor variables are factor variables. It seems that for BR all the predictors has to be numeric. So how do I deal with this? Should I convert factors to integers?

Comment: Use dummy binary variables for factors or one hot encoding with feature hashing.

Comment: Thanks Sandipan! I tried dummy binary variable, but I face memory issue as my data is relatively bigger with lot of factor labels. I don't know much about feature hashing.. would that be less memory intensive?

Comment: Yes feature hashing will be